# Condition based on BranchPythonOperator

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have some Custom Operators of the form

```
class DataPreparationOperator(BaseOperator):

template_fields = ['file']

def __init__(self, file, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.file = file


...

def execute(self, context):
    filename = f'prepared_data_{str(time()*1000).replace(".","_")}.json'
    DataDownloader(filename, self.filters()).dataframe_downloader()
    
    return filename
```

(...)

```
class DataPreparationOperatorArrivals(DataPreparationOperator):

template_fields = ['file']

def __init__(self, file, **kwargs):
    super(DataPreparationOperatorArrivals, self).__init__(file=file, **kwargs)

...
def execute(self, context):
    filename = f'prepared_data_{str(time()*1000).replace(".","_")}.json'
    DataDownloader(filename, self.charge_change()).dataframe_downloader()
    
    return filename
```

(...)

The operators are executed based on a BranchPythonOperator, in my dag looks like the following

```
def choose_data_preparation_operator(**kwargs):
    if float(kwargs.get("arrival_factor")) != 1.0:
        return ['data_preparation_arrivals_change', 'parameters_constructor']
    else:
        return ['data_preparation_normal', 'parameters_constructor']

opr_data_preparation_path = BranchPythonOperator(
    provide_context=True,
    task_id='choose_data_preparation_path',
    python_callable=choose_data_preparation_operator,
    op_kwargs = {'arrival_factor': '{{ dag_run.conf["arrival_factor"] }}'}
    )

opr_data_prep = DataPreparationOperator(
    task_id ='data_preparation_normal',
    file = 'data.json'
    )

opr_data_prep_arr = DataPreparationOperatorArrivals(
    task_id ='data_preparation_arrivals_change',
    file = 'data.json'
    )
```

As you can see, both operators return a filename,  now i want to use another Custom operator  and use the respective filename to call this file in another step, for example

```
opr_parameters_constructor = ParametersConstructor(
    task_id ='parameters_constructor',
    file = '{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="CHOOSE_THE_CORRECT_TASK_ID") }}',
    initial_time = '{{ dag_run.conf.get("initial_time") }}',
    final_time = '{{ dag_run.conf.get("final_time") }}',
    )
```

My question is, how can i put the correct **task_id** selected in the BranchPythonOperator?, i.e, the CHOOSE_THE_CORRECT_TASK_ID variable in the last piece of code.

Thanks a lot for any help :D

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge recently.

I created xcom_push operation in the first task to indicate where the file should go for each separate task. The following steps would then use the xcom_pull operations to get the file location. Finally, I extended the operators `pre_execute` function, to overwrite some variables with xcom_pulls again.

However, I believe that in your case its just much simpler to create to separate instances of the same operator. That way you don't have to do this complicated matching, and changing of variables, based on which task ran. Instead you simply write two operators where each match one of the two tasks.